# Select the next first div

Tags: jquery

How to select the `info_area` with the `btn`? I've tried with next, find and closest method as I see in others questions but is not working. Any advice ?

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(event) {
  content = $(this).closest('.info_area')
  content.slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <div class="btn">
    info
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info_area">
  Some info...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select it with `.parent().siblings()`

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
    content = $(this).parent().siblings('.info_area');
    content.slideToggle();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <div class="btn">
    info
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info_area">
  Some info...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The closest() method returns the first ancestor of the selected element. An ancestor is a parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, and so on. You have to use parent selector to get `item` element and use `siblings` or `next` to select elements on the same level:

```
content = $(this).parent().siblings('.info_area');
content = $(this).parent().next('.info_area');
content = $(this).parent().next();
```

Example:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
    content = $(this).parent().siblings('.info_area');
    
    content1 = $(this).parent().next('.info_area');
    
    content2 = $(this).parent().next();

    //content.slideToggle();
    console.log(content.text());
    console.log(content1.text());
    console.log(content2.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <button class="btn">
    info
  </button>
</div>
<div class="info_area">
  Some info...
</div>
```

Comment: @stig Garet I can't understand why you choose pedram's answer even it's too late ? this is not fair

Answer (score 2):

[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up the DOM for ancestors, but you can go up a level and use [`siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) from `.item`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="btn">
    info
  </div>
</div>
<div class="info_area">
  Some info...
</div>

<script>
  $('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
    $(this).parent('.item').siblings('.info_area').slideToggle();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @kchason, for your clear explanation. It's exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: Just a note: *No need to call `class` name when it just have one parent  or etc..*

Comment: I agree that it's optional, but I like to include them, partially out of habit, and partially because there may be multiple situations where `.btn`'s parent has a sibling classed `info_area`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like :

```
<script>
  $('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
    var content = $(this).closest(".item").next(".info_area");
    content.slideToggle();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this.

```
<script>
  $('.btn').on('click', function (event) {
    var content = $(".info_area");
    content.slideToggle();
  });
</script>
```